# Rotate UVs in shader and contains result into quad with repeat edge pixels

Tags: unity, shaders, rotation, matrix

I ask for help - I need to rotate the UV scan inside the quad by a certain angle (set by a parameter) so that the result is embedded in the original UV, and the missing areas are repeat edge pixels. Example in the picture. Unity. How to do it? I can only simply rotate the scan, but not reduce it.

[image: Required rotation type]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe someone will need it?

```
o.spriteCoord.xy = v.texcoord.xy;
o.spriteCoord.zw = float2(1, 1);
                    
o.spriteCoord.x = (o.spriteCoord.x - 0.5) * _BoundsX + 0.5;
o.spriteCoord.y = (o.spriteCoord.y - 0.5) * _BoundsY + 0.5;
                    
o.spriteCoord.xy = rotateUV(o.spriteCoord.xy, _Rotation);
                    
o.spriteCoord.x = (o.spriteCoord.x - 0.5) / _ScaleX + 0.5;
o.spriteCoord.y = (o.spriteCoord.y - 0.5) / _ScaleY + 0.5;
```

Where bounds is the size in unit of the global width and height, and scale is the desired image scale